# HTML5 popup box

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am looking to code a popup box into my simple HTML 5/Javascript/Jquery page and was wondering if there is a 'right' way to do it.

The purpose of the box is to be a form asking a few questions and then to disappear when a button is clicked.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: show your code want you did yet

Comment: There is a [dialog element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/commands.html#the-dialog-element) in html5, which eventually might well be the "right" way to do it. But it's new and there are no implementations yet, AFAIK, so for now go with the jquery solution.

Comment: not for homework, but i am new to html5,css and jquery.

Answer (score 3):

try jquery ui dialog box. [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

make sure you include the Jquery and jquery ui resources (JS, CSS Files). in order to get the desired result.

you can chose Source as CDN 
like this

```
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<div id="yourDiv">
some content
</div>
```

//jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('#yourDiv').dialog({
     modal:true
}); // setup dialog. 


$('#yourDiv').dialog('open');//open dialog
});
```

Comment: Not sure i follow, i am extremely new to this. Do you mean that the HTML above is the popup with 'some content' and this is fired from the js below it?